# white spots on top of indian pickle

Tags: yeast, fermentation, mold, pickles

I hav made carrot pickle in lemon juice 15 days ago . some white spots are formed on the top of the pickle and at the sides of the glass jar.
Is the pickle safe to consume ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not very safe to eat because those white spots are fungi.